# How do I filter everything except tweets by people I'm actually following?

Tags: twitter, retweet

I'm coming back to give Twitter another try after a time away.

For now, what I want to do is this: there are a number of people I want to follow, and read their tweets, but I don't want to see *anything* else. That includes tweets mentioning my 'followeds', retweets of their stuff, and so on.

Just to clarify, here are some examples. I'm following @Moses, but not @Pharaoh:

```
Yes: @Moses tweets    "Just got the Ten Commandments"
No:  @Pharaoh tweets: "@Moses Meh"
Yes: @Moses tweets    "@Pharaoh 's quite a nice guy"
No:  @Pharaoh rt:     "  --"-- "
Yes: @Moses rt:       "@Moses Meh"
```

Is there a way to do this? And, if possible, all the other crap that Twitter throws at me?

On-the-Web, Windows, or Android clients are OK.

Comment: Isn't that the default? The third example tweet would not appear to you unless you also follow @Pharaoh, but the other four work as you expect them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter web site will only show you the Tweets (and re-Tweets) of people you are following directly. The only exception to this is if the Tweet starts with `@username` and you are *not* following `username` then you won't see the Tweet.

So in your examples you should see Tweets 1 and 5. All the others will be hidden from you.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Total fail on my part. Sorry, and please feel free to flag for deletion as a dorky question. My problem was that I was following someone who was rt'ing a lot of very boring stuff

Comment: @Brent.Longborough - there's no such thing as a dorky question :)

Comment: But I should have looked more carefully before losing my temper...